# Search for similar strings and generate translation

Tags: vb.net, string, replace

I am working on a program with a database that translates "known" strings.

For example if i have "the car is blue" it looks in the database for this exact string and takes the corresponding translation and pastes it there if the string is stored in the database.

So far all is working fine.

Problem is that many times I have a sentence like "there are 3 blue cars in the park" but my database has the sentence "there are 2 blue cars in the park" stored.

What i would need is that the program looks up the database for strings that are identical but with different numbers. (Sqlite database)

So far it should not be too difficult. It will return the translated text but with the wrong numbers. Now I would need to replace the numbers in the text to the coorect ones. this also wouldnt be too difficult. But the problem is that one sentence could have more than one number, and in the translated text the order of the numbers is different.

For example the sentence "there are 3 cars with 2 seats in the park" once translated could become "there are 2 seats in 3 cars in the park" (obviously in the proper Language)

the numbers have switched and i need this to be taken into account when generating the new translation. How can this final part be solved?

Thanks

EDIT:

I had an idea but i am not sure it works:

I have my original string "there are 3 cars in the park with 2 seats"

i search for the string with no numbers and get the one with wrong numbers.

for example: "there are 4 cars in the park with 5 seats"

I compare the two sentences and know that every "3" is replaced by a "4" and every 2 is replaced by a "5"

i run a string replace on the returned translated text and replace all the numbers...

BUT while i am writing i am noticing a problem: if i have the sentence "there are 3 cars int he park with 2 seats" and the returned sentence from the database is "there are 5 cars in the park with 5 seats" then it wont work as the result would be "there are 3 cars in the park with 3 seats".. do you have an idea on how to overcome this last part?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `string.Format` and store the strings in your database as:
`There are {0} cars with {1} seats`

This would then become in the code:
`string.Format("There are {0} cars with {1} seats", amountOfCars, amountOfSeats);`

Of course this makes things more complicated for the translators and maintainers ("Is {0} the amount of seats? Or was it the amount of cars? Hmm...") so you could use simple Replaces:

```
"There are {#cars} cars with {#seats} seats"
    .Replace("{#cars}", amountOfCars)      
    .Replace("{#seats}", amountOfSeats);
```

If this would make things too complicated, perhaps you'll need to look into some sort of templating engine / library.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion. please look at my comment to Konrad kokosa s answer

Answer (score 0):

Build it based on the regular expression and referenced groups, for example, regular expression:

```
there are (\d+) cars with (\d+) seats in the park
```

can be replaced by (this is in Polish):

```
Na parkingu jest $2 miejsc w $1 samochodach.
```

Then simply use [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) method:

```
Dim pattern As String = "there are (\d+) cars with (\d+) seats in the park"
Dim replacement As String = "Na parkingu jest $2 miejsc w $1 samochodach."
Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, replacement)
```

**Note:** You can make those patters more readable for pleaple by using named groups:

```
there are (?<Cars>\d+) cars with (?<Seats>\d+) seats in the park
Na parkingu jest ${Seats} miejsc w ${Cars} samochodach.
```

Comment: thanks for the tipp.. problem is the list in the database cannot be changed. it gets imported from premade lists and can be literally ANY string.. its a list of strings that have been used at least once by a third party software. All i know is the original string, the corrisponding similar string, and the translation of the similar string. from this i need to get the translation of the original string.

Comment: @user2452250, seems to me that you need some automatic process of building pair of regular expressions (like provided by me) from the pair of translation that you have so things gets tricky indeed...

Comment: i had an idea and am not sure it works.. updating first post and will report back